# Using the chrome extension debugger breaks the application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I run the code below by clicking the extensions icon I get to see the 'Mainscript' alert from mainscript.js.

When I use the Dev-Tools debugger and put a break on:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "mainscript.js"}); in background.js
```

and then click continue I get the error message:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.
```

Which I think is because I'm now running executeScript in the context of the debugger window .

How do I stop the debugger causing the error?

Manifest:

```
{
   "name": "Enable/Disable",
   "version": "1.0",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "description": "Enables/Disables",

   "permissions": 
   [
     "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/*",
     "activeTab"
   ],

   "browser_action": 
   {
      "default_icon": 
      {
         "16": "images/Icon_ENABLED.png"
      }
   },

  "background": 
  {
     "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener
(
   function(tab) 
   {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "mainscript.js"});
   }
);
```

mainscript.js

```
alert('Mainscript');
```

Comment: Specify `tab.id` instead of `null`.

Comment: Once again I'm in your debt.
Why does calling a script care about the tab anyway?
My code is at browser level.

Comment: It's not at browser level. The code is executed in the background page. Executing it inside a popup would be working inside the browser level since the popup is "tied" to the specific page its been opened at while the background page has no default tab.